# Implementations of algorithms without imputation of missing values

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, missing-data

I would like to know if there are any implementations of machine learning algorithms in python which can work even if there are missing values in the dataset. Please note that I don't want algorithms imputing the missing values first.(I could have done that using the Imputer package ). I would like to know about the implementation of algorithms which work even if there are missing values present in the dataset without imputation.

Comment: I don't know exact names of such algorithms, but I think you can implement any decision-tree based algo in such style. Let's assume that you have binary tree, and you are traversing it to get some class, if you don't know exact value of some feature, and you must choose some child-node based on this missing value - you can consider both childnodes in further traversing as nodes which could contain possible solutions. So you are searching your solutions not in one child-node, but in two combined child-nodes (maybe weighted somehow)

Comment: Also, I think that most of such algos will impute missing values implicitly.

Comment: If the sample size is large enough, one solution might be to build separate models with and without the feature with missing values.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK scikit-learn doesn't have ML algorithms that can work with missing values without preprocessing them first. R does though.